# How to test continuity on signal wire?

Tags: electronics, led-strip

I’m reassembling an LED strip, SK6812, that I had cut into smaller lengths. I don’t have a lot of faith in the connectors I’m using or my ability to solder, so I’d like to test it before I put power to it. A simple continuity test is easy for the power “wires” but how do I test the signal “wire”?

Comment: The easiest way to test that is to use it, first checking that data doesn't have continuity with gnd or v+ (although that shouldn't really hurt anything anyway).

Comment: If you have a multimeter, that has a continuity or resistance measurement mode, you can use this. And when you suspect the connectors being bad, you could just measure the continuity on the wires at both sides of the connector. That is the same for power and data lines